# Hide DIV content dependent on textbox value length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to hide some content in a div based on the length of a textbox value when a key is pressed. This is not working however. Is the backspace key not considered a keypress?

If you check out the JSFIDDLE below, after you type something in the text box, the info box should display, and then after everything is erased should disappear.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gE742/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.textBox').keypress(function (e) { 
        if ($('.textBox').val().length < 1) {       
            $('.infoBox').fadeOut(600); 
        } else {
            $('.infoBox').fadeIn(600);
        }; 
    });
});
```

Comment: The `keypress` event fires before the value is updated. Use `keyup` instead - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/gE742/20/)

Comment: Your fiddle has extra parantheses which causes an error, see error console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you have an error in this fiddle:

```
if ($('.textBox').val().length < 1) {       
    $('.infoBox').fadeOut(600); 
});
```

Should be

```
if ($('.textBox').val().length < 1) {       
    $('.infoBox').fadeOut(600); 
}
```

Secondly, use `keyup()` instead - http://jsfiddle.net/ajthomascouk/BBu9P/